# What is this keyboard layout ? (G413)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout, logitech-keyboard

I know it's look like a silly question but I'm currently struggling to find the name of the layout of my G413 from Logitech. The Amazon page from where I buy it says it's an "US international" layout but some keys doesn't match with other US keyboards. It's more like a US and UK mixed together.

Does any one have already seen this kind of layout, or is it just an exotic one ?

[G413 Logitech](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbpcQ.jpg)

Comment: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000621393&pID=b9ce93e5-7db0-11e9-aa7f-175348c76fa8 would be a good place to ask Logitech what they call it.

Comment: This one got me too... I'm a bit miffed, I really enjoy the new G413 keyboard, but having to change typing habits because of this strange nonstandard layout seems a bit... unnecessary. :/

Comment: Fun fact: if you visit the official Logitec page, then the correct US layout only shows up in their fancy ad/reveal video... which was probably created independently from physical reality... https://www.logitechg.com/en-ch/products/gaming-keyboards/g413-mechanical-gaming-keyboard.920-008473.html

Answer (score 1):

The only difference to a US keyboard is the form of the return key and the placement of the | \ key, and the presence of the € on the 5 key.

Nothing UK-ish here, all the Shift-Characters on the number keys are the same as on the US layout, while the UK-layout would differ here.

The form of the return key is probably because that’s also used like this for all european keyboards, so Logitech can use the same physical key for all keyboard variants. Look up various language variants of the G413, and it always looks identical (except for the printing/translucency on the keys)

Comment: It's a very odd hybrid - the Enter key is ISO, the missing key left of z makes it ANSI… as does the shift-number placement. So it ends up being neither ;)